# NSZombie stopped working after distribution provisioning profile added

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nszombie

I was using NSZombie just fine to debug my project, but now it fails to show anything at all when I run the Profiler. The only change I have made that would seem to affect this is the addition of an ad-hc provisioning profile.

The NSZombie environment variable is still enabled for the Run scheme, and the Profile scheme shows it as well, since the Profile scheme is set to "Use the Run action's options."

But when I choose the Allocations Profile Instrument in XCode 4, it offers no report on my NSZombie behavior. I even deliberated added these lines:

```
NSString *test=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"hi"];
[test release];
[test release];
```

This should create a NSZombie, but there is no Instruments report like there used to be.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you run this code? `BOOL zombies = getenv("NSZombieEnabled") || getenv("NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled"); NSLog(@"Running %@ zombies", zombies ? @"WITH" : @"WITHOUT");`

Comment: the following prints to the console when I run this code: `Running WITH zombies`

Comment: i'm using the Allocations feature in the Instruments Profile window. I recall that is the correct one. And I'm setting it to include "record reference counts." But when there is a zombie-related crash, it provides no popup like it used ot.

Comment: ah, wouldn't you know it... it's because i had forgotten that you cannot run zombie detection except in simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as noted in my comment, the answer was simple: must be in simulator to use this feature.